# shapado: how to use it after installation

Tags: shapado

I have installed 'shapado' on my server.  I can run the server with no error.  What do I do next to hook up to it?  What url do I point my browser to?  There is no html file in the shaped installation.

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, I found the answer by Google'ing around:  The URL is localhost.lan:3000